# Access Reporting displaying data in report?

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm making a simple inventory report for the user. What I'm allowing the user to do is, enter a FROM and TO Date and only filter by those dates for the report. This is a VB6 information, so I pass the value to an empty form with a filed FROM and then use that in the report. In the report, I'm trying to display the Month and Year, ex November 2015 if the report request is for November. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I would create an unbound field on the form to display the first of the month following the date inputted by the user, using standard date functions DatePart and DateSerial. So if the user inputs a date in November the unbound field displays 01 December 2015 and your report is based on that date.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an unbound field on the form to display the first of the month following the date inputted by the user, using standard date functions DatePart and DateSerial. So if the user inputs a date in November the unbound field displays 01 December 2015 and your report is based on that date.

Comment: How would I go about finding the count of inventory from say 1/1/2000 to the last day of the previous month of FROM date?

Comment: I'd use DCount but I think I need more information from you to completely understand and answer. Here's a part suggestion: DCount("ID",[Table or Query], "Between #01/01/2000# And " & [MyDate]). MyDate would be a Dim on the procedure equating to the unbound field I mentioned.